# Form submission in Play framework 2.5.12 Scala

Tags: forms, scala, playframework-2.0

I am new to play framework. I am trying to create a simple form submission web application using Play Framework 2.5.12. I went through the Play documentation [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaForms) but getting lot of compilation error in this and this document is also some what confusing.

1. play-solr-zk\build.sbt

   ```
   name := """play-solr-zk"""
   version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
   lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
   scalaVersion := "2.12.1"

   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     "org.apache.solr" % "solr-solrj" % "4.10.3",
     "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.3.1"
   )
   ```
2. play-solr-zk\conf\routes

   ```
   # An example controller showing a sample home page
   GET     /                           controllers.HomeController.index
   # An example controller showing how to use dependency injection
   GET     /count                      controllers.CountController.count
   # An example controller showing how to write asynchronous code
   GET     /message                    controllers.AsyncController.message

   # Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
   GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
   ```
3. play-solr-zk\app\controllers\HomeController.scala

   ```
   package controllers

   import javax.inject._
   import play.api._
   import play.api.mvc._

   //FORMS
   import play.api.data._
   import play.api.data.Forms._

   import models.User

      @Singleton
   class HomeController @Inject() extends Controller{

       def index = Action {
           println("Hi!")
           Ok(views.html.index(userForm))
       }


   case class UserData(supplierID: String)

   val userForm = Form(
           mapping(
                   "supplierID" -> text  
                   )(UserData.apply)(UserData.unapply)

           )

   val anyData = Map("supplierID" -> "1")

   def userPost = Action{ implicit request =>
           userForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
           formWithErrors => {
               // binding failure, you retrieve the form containing errors:
               BadRequest(views.html.index(formWithErrors))
           },
           userData => {
               /* binding success, you get the actual value. */
               val newUser = models.User(userData.supplierID)
               val id = models.User.create(newUser)
               Redirect(routes.HomeController.index())
           }
   )
       }
   }
   ```
4. play-solr-zk\app\views\index.scala.html

   ```
   @(userForm: Form[UserData])(implicit messages: Messages)

   @import helper._
   @main("Welcome to Play") {

       @helper.form(action = routes.HomeController.userPost()) {
           @helper.inputText(userForm("name"))
       }
   }
   ```

I am getting four comlilation errors:

1. at this line `Ok(views.html.index(userForm))`. Error msg: `type mismatch; found : play#37.api#18359.data#19005.Form#23899[HomeController#17830.this.UserData#248073] required: play#37.api#18359.data#19005.Form#23899[String#109465]`
2. at this line `BadRequest(views.html.index(formWithErrors))`. Error msg: `type mismatch; found : play#37.api#18359.data#19005.Form#23899[HomeController#17830.this.UserData#248073] required: play#37.api#18359.data#19005.Form#23899[String#109465]`
3. at this line `val newUser = models.User(userData.supplierID)`. Error msg: `object User is not a member of package models#39 Note: class User#166014 exists, but it has no companion object.`
4. at this line `val id = models.User.create(newUser)`. Error msg: `object User is not a member of package models#39 Note: class User#166014 exists, but it has no companion object.`

I just want a simple form submission. So that I can get the data comming from the form in my Controller and can use the data for further processing. Please help me where I am missing any thing.

Comment: for errors 3 and 4, you should probably give the code from `models.User`...

Comment: Errors 1 and 2, you should move your `UserData` model to separate file, and refer to it from view as `my.package.UserData`.. Also, if you use ScalaIDE you'll always get cryptic errors, until you do `eclipse` in sbt and refresh the project...